# Caught speeding in New Zealand

Tags: driving, driving-licenses, new-zealand

I was driving in New Zealand using my UK driver's license. I got caught speeding and had to pay a fine.

Does this driving offense get reflected on my UK license? Is the [DVLA](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/driver-and-vehicle-licensing-agency) informed and something sent to my home address in the UK?

Or, is it just the fine here and my name on the NZ database? Also, how long does the offense stick?

Comment: was this a speed camera or did you get stopped by police?

Comment: I have had this question come up in practice.  Essentially 'vizgne's' answer is correct and there's nothing I could add to it except it's a possible hit if you try to emigrate there.  Like he says, watch out for a CCJ.

Comment: It was the police

Answer (score 7):

There are a few issues here:

1. New Zealand also uses a demerit point system for driving offences, though the scale is different than in the UK. If you [receive 100 points in a two year period](http://www.police.govt.nz/faq/how-do-i-find-out-more-about-demerit-points), your license will be suspended (disqualified) for three months. This only applies in New Zealand, though; notice of your fine and points won't be sent to the UK.
2. The points you receive for speeding depend on [how far over the speed limit you were](http://www.nzta.govt.nz/licence/offences-penalties/demerit.html), and can be from 10 to 50 points. Again, that only applies in New Zealand, but if you return sometime in the next two years, those points will be there.
3. Because of this, if you have fines or even parking tickets owing, [you may be stopped at the airport](http://www.police.govt.nz/faq/travelling-to-from-nz-with-fines) when you attempt to leave the country, or if you aren't stopped then, if you ever return. I would recommend you be sure to [pay the fine before you leave](http://www.police.govt.nz/contact-us/how-pay-infringement-fee/pay-police-infringement-fee), and carry proof of that payment when you depart the country.

You should also keep the record of the fine and the fact that you paid it, in case [the rental car company tries to claim that you didn't pay it](http://www.police.govt.nz/faq/rental-car-infringement-dispute).

This answer was sourced entirely from the [New Zealand Police](http://www.police.govt.nz/) and [New Zealand Transport Agency](http://www.nzta.govt.nz/) web sites.

Answer (score 5):

DVLA won't be informed and it wont affect your driving record.

However the offence will stick effectively forever, and [according to DriverAbroad.com](http://www.driverabroad.com/self-drive/foreign-speeding-and-parking-fines/)

> Some countries have a more stringent approach than others. I’ve heard a number of stories of **New Zealand** authorities employing debt collection agencies abroad to pursue fines for instance. I’ve also heard of some European countries ,especially in Scandinavia and Eastern Europe checking the licences of drivers in foreign registered cars crossing their borders for outstanding fines.

This could lead to a default listing in your home country which would affect your credit profile.

Additionally, if you were driving a rental, they may charge you the fine directly.

Comment: From the question I interpret Sarah did pay the fine.

Comment: Haven't paid yet only got it yesterday.Thanks for the info though